# do i have to have my own server desktop to run mongodb on web?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

Friends, i am very new on mongodb node and jade. I setup my first fullstack on my localhost as the tutorials always teach on localhost. Now, I want to see my first app running on internet just to try. So, how does this work? how do we run node jade mongodb stack on internet not on localhost.

Comment: It's more complicated than can be explained here

Comment: You rent a server with a permanent internet connection and set it up to run all this stuff. Any further questions? Ask on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your best bet is to use something like Heroku. They can work with MongoHQ to get you working:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongohq

If you're feeling braver you can look at digitalocean who can rent you a very cheap ubuntu box:

http://www.digitalocean.com

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Another good hosting option is [modulus.io](https://modulus.io). As a beginner I found them very easy to use, with no need to set up a separate mongo host.  You used to be able to get a one month free trial.